# New-SPProfileServiceApplication using Powershell command

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

I am Trying to create the **"New SP Profile Service Application"** using Powershell command

New-SPProfileServiceApplication -Name SharedServicesMoss2007 –ApplicationPool "SharePoint Web Services Default" –ProfileDBName "WSS_Content_38216"

I  identified it is showing error as **"Missing expression after unary operator '-' "**

at **-Name** key word .Can any one help me how can i solve the issue

Comment: Careful with that Profile DB Name. It looks like a content DB

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell?

If not, have you loaded the SharePoint Module?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Follow this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx

Also, quote all your parameters:

```
-Name "SharedServicesMoss2007"
```